# Google Sheets formula to reference to another cell value that contains a sheet name & range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I have a spreadsheet with 2 sheets (Dashboard,Sheet2)

I would like to find a way to use a VLOOKUP formula to get the Sheet name & range from a specific cell, then perform the lookup function.

On the Dashboard sheet, it looks like...

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sheet Name & Range: | Sheet2!A1:B10 |
| 2 | =VLOOKUP("Key", **B1**, 2, FALSE) |  |

I have tried...

`=VLOOKUP("Key", B1, 2, FALSE)`

`=VLOOKUP("Key", B1:B1, 2, FALSE)`

`=VLOOKUP("Key", '"&B1&"', 2, FALSE)`

`=VLOOKUP("Key", FORMULATEXT(B1), 2, FALSE)`

The reason why I am looking for a solution this because Sheet2 is updated daily by Alteryx. It does so by deleting all the cells, then adding the new data. Every time it does this, it causes a REF# error and breaks the formula.

Any help or links to learn how to do this would be greatly apricated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `INDIRECT()` function.

```
=VLOOKUP("Key", INDIRECT(B1), 2, FALSE)
```